# How to select the posts of friends of a user from the below tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: please check the screenshot on the below link for the tables]

> Table1: posts
> Table 2: friends

I want to display the posts of friends of user(say with **`userId=3`**) in a website so what **two table query** should i use?
Here user_one_id and user_two_id are friends if **`status=1`**

Comment: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userId IN (SELECT user_one_id FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = 3 AND status = 1 UNION SELECT user_two_id FROM friends WHERE user_one_id = 3 AND status = 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p JOIN friends f on p.userId=f.user_one_id OR p.userId=f.user_two_id 
WHERE userId=3
```